# List of list access part of elements correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to access list of list in python 3.

```
a = [
     [ 1, 2, 3 ],
     [ 4, 5, 6 ],
     [ 7, 8, 9 ]
    ]
```

I need  to access the second and third elements in rightmost column.
I want to get:
    `[6, 9]` as a list

but,

```
from numpy import matrix
from numpy import array

a = [
     [ 1, 2, 3 ],
     [ 4, 5, 6 ],
     [ 7, 8, 9 ]
    ]

ab =    matrix(a)
ab[1:3][2]

ab =    array(a)
ab[1:3][2]
```

None of them work.

How to access part of  elements correctly?

Comment: What you want is `ab[1:3,2]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the `second` column starting at the `first` row:

```
In [27]: x = np.arange(1, 10).reshape(3,3)
# array([[1, 2, 3],
#        [4, 5, 6],
#        [7, 8, 9]])
In [31]: x[1:,2]
Out[31]: array([6, 9])
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple list comprehension task:

```
In [507]: a = [
     ...:      [ 1, 2, 3 ],
     ...:      [ 4, 5, 6 ],
     ...:      [ 7, 8, 9 ]
     ...:     ]
     ...:     
In [508]: [x[2] for x in a[1:]]
Out[508]: [6, 9]
```

lists also have a hand 'transpose' idiom:

```
In [509]: list(zip(*a))
Out[509]: [(1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9)]
In [510]: list(zip(*a))[2][1:]
Out[510]: (6, 9)
```

If you make it into an array

```
In [511]: np.array(a)
Out[511]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
In [512]: np.array(a)[1:,2]
Out[512]: array([6, 9])
```

---

Notice that I indexed the array with `[1:, 2]`.  If I try to do it piecemeal:

```
In [513]: np.array(a)[1:3]
Out[513]: 
array([[4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])   # still a 2d array
In [514]: _[2]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-514-084060d1880a> in <module>()
----> 1 _[2]

IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2
```

The `[1:3]` selects the right rows, but the next `[2] tries to select rows again; it doesn't select from columns.  To do that use my kind of expression.